# object doesn't stop on position after jump javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a problem with my game character. It supposes to jump and fall to the ground by pressing the spacebar and fall in the canyon if over it. But if it manages to jump over the canyon it should land on a ground position. Unfortunately, my game character is finding itself much underground after jumping above the canyon. I can't figure out why.

```js
var gameChar_x;
var gameChar_y;
var floorPos_y;

var isLeft;
var isRight;
var isPlummeting;
var isFalling;
var collectable;
var canyon;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1024, 576);
  floorPos_y = (height * 3) / 4;
  gameChar_x = width / 2;
  gameChar_y = floorPos_y;

  isLeft = false;
  isRight = false;
  isPlummeting = false;
  isFalling = false;
  collectable = {
    x_pos: 150,
    y_pos: 420,
    size: 1.1,
    isFound: false
  };
  canyon = {
    x_pos: 280,
    width: 100
  };
}

function draw() {
  ///////////DRAWING CODE//////////

  background(100, 155, 255); //fill the sky blue

  noStroke();
  fill(0, 155, 0);
  rect(0, floorPos_y, width, height - floorPos_y); //draw some green ground

  //draw the canyon
  if (
    gameChar_x > canyon.x_pos &&
    gameChar_x < canyon.x_pos + canyon.width &&
    gameChar_y >= floorPos_y
  ) {
    isPlummeting = true;
    gameChar_y += 10;
  } else {
    isPlummeting = false;
  }
  fill(99);
  rect(canyon.x_pos, floorPos_y, canyon.width, height);
  fill(70);
  rect(canyon.x_pos + 10, floorPos_y, canyon.width - 20, height);
  //water
  fill(19, 26, 130);
  rect(canyon.x_pos + 10, floorPos_y + 80, canyon.width - 20, height / 4);

  //VINYL
  if (dist(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, collectable.x_pos, collectable.y_pos) < 20) {
    collectable.isFound = true;
  }

  if (collectable.isFound == false) {
    fill(0);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      30 * collectable.size,
      30 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(112, 128, 144);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      26 * collectable.size,
      26 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      25 * collectable.size,
      25 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    fill(112, 128, 144);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      22 * collectable.size,
      22 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      21 * collectable.size,
      21 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    fill(112, 128, 144);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      19 * collectable.size,
      19 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      18 * collectable.size,
      18 * collectable.size
    );

    fill(148, 0, 148);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      15 * collectable.size,
      15 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
  }

  //the game character
  if (isLeft && isFalling) {
    // add your jumping-left code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 6, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 14, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 31, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 46, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 27, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x - 3, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 56, gameChar_x - 3, gameChar_y - 62);
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 63);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x - 6, gameChar_y - 30, gameChar_x - 20, gameChar_y - 35);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 13,
      gameChar_y - 47,
      gameChar_x - 23,
      gameChar_y - 40,
      gameChar_x - 13,
      gameChar_y - 43
    );
  } else if (isRight && isFalling) {
    // add your jumping-right code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 6, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 14, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 31, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 46, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 27, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x + 3, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 56, gameChar_x + 3, gameChar_y - 62);
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 63);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x + 6, gameChar_y - 30, gameChar_x + 20, gameChar_y - 35);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x + 13,
      gameChar_y - 47,
      gameChar_x + 23,
      gameChar_y - 40,
      gameChar_x + 13,
      gameChar_y - 43
    );
  } else if (isLeft) {
    // add your walking left code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 4, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 15);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 6,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x - 17,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x - 6,
      gameChar_y - 36
    );
  } else if (isRight) {
    // add your walking right code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 4, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 15);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x + 6,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x + 17,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x + 6,
      gameChar_y - 36
    );
  } else if (isFalling || isPlummeting) {
    // add your jumping facing forwards code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 23, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 13, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 13, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 36, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 50, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 33, 3, 3);
    //eyes
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 52, 2, 2);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 52, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 61, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 66);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 59, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 66);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 61, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 66);
    //arms
    line(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 37, gameChar_x - 15, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 37, gameChar_x + 15, gameChar_y - 57);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 2,
      gameChar_y - 49,
      gameChar_x - 10,
      gameChar_y - 43,
      gameChar_x + 2,
      gameChar_y - 49
    );
  } else {
    // add your standing front facing code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eyes
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arms
    line(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x - 15, gameChar_y - 17);
    line(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x + 15, gameChar_y - 17);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 2,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x - 10,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x + 2,
      gameChar_y - 39
    );
  }

  ///////////INTERACTION CODE//////////
  //Put conditional statements to move the game character below here
  if (isLeft == true) {
    gameChar_x -= 4;
  }
  if (isRight == true) {
    gameChar_x += 4;
  }
  //jumping
  if (gameChar_y < floorPos_y) {
    gameChar_y += 4;
    isFalling = true;
  } else isFalling = false;
}

function keyPressed() {
  // if statements to control the animation of the character when
  // keys are pressed.
  if (keyCode == 37) {
    isLeft = true;
  }

  if (keyCode == 39) {
    isRight = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == 32 && gameChar_y == floorPos_y) {
    gameChar_y -= 100;
  }
}

function keyReleased() {
  // if statements to control the animation of the character when
  // keys are released.
  if (keyCode == 37) {
    isLeft = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == 39) {
    isRight = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-N4kV7GkNv7QR7RX9YF/olywyIgIwNvfEe2nZtfyj73HdjCUkAfOBDbcuJ/cTaN04JKRnw1YG1wnUyNKMsNgg3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be that your character is allowed to move through the sides of your canyon. You're not checking for wall collision before adding or subtracting its x-position.

I've added wall-checks to your interaction code:

```js
var gameChar_x;
var gameChar_y;
var floorPos_y;

var isLeft;
var isRight;
var isPlummeting;
var isFalling;
var collectable;
var canyon;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1024, 576);
  floorPos_y = (height * 3) / 4;
  gameChar_x = width / 2;
  gameChar_y = floorPos_y;

  isLeft = false;
  isRight = false;
  isPlummeting = false;
  isFalling = false;
  collectable = {
    x_pos: 150,
    y_pos: 420,
    size: 1.1,
    isFound: false
  };
  canyon = {
    x_pos: 280,
    width: 100
  };
}

function draw() {
  ///////////DRAWING CODE//////////

  background(100, 155, 255); //fill the sky blue

  noStroke();
  fill(0, 155, 0);
  rect(0, floorPos_y, width, height - floorPos_y); //draw some green ground

  //draw the canyon
  if (
    gameChar_x > canyon.x_pos &&
    gameChar_x < canyon.x_pos + canyon.width &&
    gameChar_y >= floorPos_y
  ) {
    isPlummeting = true;
    gameChar_y += 10;
  } else {
    isPlummeting = false;
  }
  fill(99);
  rect(canyon.x_pos, floorPos_y, canyon.width, height);
  fill(70);
  rect(canyon.x_pos + 10, floorPos_y, canyon.width - 20, height);
  //water
  fill(19, 26, 130);
  rect(canyon.x_pos + 10, floorPos_y + 80, canyon.width - 20, height / 4);

  //VINYL
  if (dist(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, collectable.x_pos, collectable.y_pos) < 20) {
    collectable.isFound = true;
  }

  if (collectable.isFound == false) {
    fill(0);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      30 * collectable.size,
      30 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(112, 128, 144);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      26 * collectable.size,
      26 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      25 * collectable.size,
      25 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    fill(112, 128, 144);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      22 * collectable.size,
      22 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      21 * collectable.size,
      21 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    fill(112, 128, 144);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      19 * collectable.size,
      19 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      18 * collectable.size,
      18 * collectable.size
    );

    fill(148, 0, 148);
    ellipse(
      collectable.x_pos,
      collectable.y_pos,
      15 * collectable.size,
      15 * collectable.size
    );
    fill(0);
  }

  //the game character
  if (isLeft && isFalling) {
    // add your jumping-left code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 6, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 14, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 31, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 46, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 27, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x - 3, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 56, gameChar_x - 3, gameChar_y - 62);
    line(gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x - 9, gameChar_y - 63);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x - 6, gameChar_y - 30, gameChar_x - 20, gameChar_y - 35);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 13,
      gameChar_y - 47,
      gameChar_x - 23,
      gameChar_y - 40,
      gameChar_x - 13,
      gameChar_y - 43
    );
  } else if (isRight && isFalling) {
    // add your jumping-right code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 20, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 6, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 14, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 31, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 46, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 27, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 11, gameChar_y - 48, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x + 3, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 56, gameChar_x + 3, gameChar_y - 62);
    line(gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 57, gameChar_x + 9, gameChar_y - 63);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x + 6, gameChar_y - 30, gameChar_x + 20, gameChar_y - 35);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x + 13,
      gameChar_y - 47,
      gameChar_x + 23,
      gameChar_y - 40,
      gameChar_x + 13,
      gameChar_y - 43
    );
  } else if (isLeft) {
    // add your walking left code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 12, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 4, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 15);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 6,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x - 17,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x - 6,
      gameChar_y - 36
    );
  } else if (isRight) {
    // add your walking right code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 12, gameChar_y - 7, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 4, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eye
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arm
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 15);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x + 6,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x + 17,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x + 6,
      gameChar_y - 36
    );
  } else if (isFalling || isPlummeting) {
    // add your jumping facing forwards code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 23, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 13, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 13, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 36, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 50, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 33, 3, 3);
    //eyes
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 52, 2, 2);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 52, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 61, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 66);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 59, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 66);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 61, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 66);
    //arms
    line(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 37, gameChar_x - 15, gameChar_y - 57);
    line(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 37, gameChar_x + 15, gameChar_y - 57);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 2,
      gameChar_y - 49,
      gameChar_x - 10,
      gameChar_y - 43,
      gameChar_x + 2,
      gameChar_y - 49
    );
  } else {
    // add your standing front facing code
    fill(255);
    stroke(1);
    strokeWeight(1);
    //lower body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 13, 20, 20);
    //legs
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y, 7, 7);
    //upper body
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 26, 15, 15);
    //head
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 40, 12, 17);
    fill(0);
    //button
    ellipse(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 23, 3, 3);
    //eyes
    ellipse(gameChar_x - 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    ellipse(gameChar_x + 2, gameChar_y - 42, 2, 2);
    stroke(116, 58, 8);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(116, 58, 8);
    //"hair"
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x - 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 49, gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 56);
    line(gameChar_x, gameChar_y - 51, gameChar_x + 5, gameChar_y - 56);
    //arms
    line(gameChar_x - 7, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x - 15, gameChar_y - 17);
    line(gameChar_x + 7, gameChar_y - 27, gameChar_x + 15, gameChar_y - 17);
    //nose
    noStroke();
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    triangle(
      gameChar_x - 2,
      gameChar_y - 39,
      gameChar_x - 10,
      gameChar_y - 33,
      gameChar_x + 2,
      gameChar_y - 39
    );
  }

  ///////////INTERACTION CODE//////////
  //Put conditional statements to move the game character below here
  if (isLeft == true) {
    var spaceLeft = gameChar_x - (canyon.x_pos + 20)
    var deltaX = gameChar_y <= floorPos_y ? 4 : Math.min(4, spaceLeft)
    gameChar_x -= deltaX;
  }
  if (isRight == true) {
    var spaceRight = (canyon.x_pos + canyon.width - 20) - gameChar_x
    var deltaX = gameChar_y <= floorPos_y ? 4 : Math.min(4, spaceRight)
    gameChar_x += deltaX;
  }
  //jumping
  if (gameChar_y < floorPos_y) {
    gameChar_y += 4;
    isFalling = true;
  } else isFalling = false;
}

function keyPressed() {
  // if statements to control the animation of the character when
  // keys are pressed.
  if (keyCode == 37) {
    isLeft = true;
  }

  if (keyCode == 39) {
    isRight = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == 32 && gameChar_y == floorPos_y) {
    gameChar_y -= 100;
  }
}

function keyReleased() {
  // if statements to control the animation of the character when
  // keys are released.
  if (keyCode == 37) {
    isLeft = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == 39) {
    isRight = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js" integrity="sha512-N4kV7GkNv7QR7RX9YF/olywyIgIwNvfEe2nZtfyj73HdjCUkAfOBDbcuJ/cTaN04JKRnw1YG1wnUyNKMsNgg3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```